Python Veify if a number is an integer
This is something that I have not been able to resolve.
The issue is that I am looking for an integer as an output.
I have written some sample code, which is:
tempVal1 = 4+5
print ("The value is of tempval1 integer: ", tempVal1, "\n and it is an integer ",isinstance(tempVal1, int))
tempVal2 = math.sqrt(36)
print ("The value is of tempval2 integer: ", tempVal2, "\n and it is an integer ", isinstance(tempVal2, int))

The output is
from what I can see, the ouput of the square root is coming as a float.
I have looked at operator.index(tempVal2)
and it sets everything as integer values.
The output that i am looking is to checkj if the number is an integer or not.
Can anyone advise me what steps to take?
If it was C# for example, I would try something like
if(int.TryParse(inputString, out val))


Does this answer your question? How to check if a float value is a whole number

From Python 3.12 forward, x.is_integer().

Hi Elerium, thanks that has resolved it, could you put it in a post and I will give you credit for it

@user3569147 you can give credit to the answer in the linked question if it solved your problem.

From Python 3.12 forward, you can use the aptly named .is_integer() method on both floats and ints.
On earlier versions, that method only existed on floats.

Since it only existed on floats prior to 3.12, you might also do float(n).is_integer()
